# ORACLE SQL - REGEXP_LIKE Contains First Character As a Number and Second Character as an Alphabet

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to generate a query in Oracle where i can get records that has first character in String as 3 or 4 AND second character is an alphabet. The rest can be anything else.

Something like this

```
    SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (COL1, '3[A-Za-Z]')
OR REGEXP_LIKE (COL1, '4[A-Za-z]')
```

I Do get the output but for few records the data doesn't start with 3 or 4. 
Meaning it selects those records who have 3 and An alphabet together anywhere in the column.

ex: 1057**3T**2  (10573T2). I have to query records that should start with either 3 or 4 and the next character should be a letter.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '10573T2' from dual union all
  3     select '3A1234F' from dual union all
  4     select '23XXX02' from dual union all
  5     select '4GABC23' from dual union all
  6     select '31234FX' from dual
  7    )
  8  select col
  9  from test
 10  where regexp_like(col, '(^3|^4)[[:alpha:]]');

COL
-------
3A1234F
4GABC23

SQL>
```

- begins `^` with `3` or `|` `4`
- and is followed by a letter `[[:alpha:]]`

---

As of your `^` doubts: that character has two roles:

- `[^ ... ]` - Non-Matching Character List: matches any character **not in** list ...
- `^` - Beginning of Line Anchor: match the subsequent expression only when it occurs at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Thank you very much. it works! I was in an assumption that '^' stands for NOT as in do not include characters following ^.

For Example ^3 meaning don't include 3.

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more info about the `^` character usage; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor the pattern at the beginning of the string:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(COL1, '^[34][A-Za-z]')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f2bef4bf1ce376eebd704df767e88893) is a db<>fiddle

Comment: Thanks! Although this throws an error that says it's an invalid range.
The above comment explained by Littlefoot get's the result perfectly.

Comment: @ChiragRaj . . .That was a typo in your original question that I missed.  I fixed this answer.